# RainLoop contacts suggestions autocomplete - replace with own addresses directory call

Tags: knockout.js, webmail

I have own addresses directory which provides API (well documented). Response for a search query to that directory is a JSON. I have tried to replace current RainLoop functionality for autocomplete of contact suggestions but simple I had no luck (due to lack of API documentation).

Current status is that I'm able to request results from own address directory using `ajax.suggestions-post` hook from RainLoop but I'm not able to append results to current autocomplete suggestions from contacts neither I have no idea how to filter output for those suggestions to add own data attributes.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like

```
$aResult[] = array($email_address, $full_name);
```

do the business to assign custom suggestions to suggestions from contacts for a `ajax.suggestions-post` hook.